# Client side session login using passport oauth2 for MEAN stack app

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, mean-stack

I have put together a mean stack app. I'm now working on implementing user authentification following tutorials I found here and there. I have successfully implemented passport for authentification using oauth2 from google but I can't really find any resource on how to manage authentification on the client side (Angular) to keep a user logged in. I want the user to login and then navigate through my app freely without needing to query the server for authentification each time he wants to access a restricted angular route.

Here is my thinking on how to solve this:
The server should only authenticate a user but should not change his location in the app which is what I do with the successful->redirect when I manage the callback from google. Instead of redirecting, I should just send back a token to the angular app that will be stored on the client's side and which will prove that a user is logged in. To unlog, I just need to delete the token on the client side and send a request to the server for him to call logout() to google which will log the user out of the server. The problem with that approach is that I only know the user is logged in when my app gets Google's callback which means I can't pass a token to my client in a query response like I would for a regular email + password login situation.

Here are code samples from my server :

The authentification routes from my server:

```
router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
              successRedirect : '/',
              failureRedirect : '/login'
}));
```

The strategy from passport:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({

        clientID        : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret    : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL     : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,

    },
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {




        process.nextTick(function() {


            User.findOne({ 'id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (user) {


                    return done(null, user);

                }

                if(profile.emails[0].value.indexOf("@mycompany.edu") == -1){
                  return done("user not from mycompany"); 
                } 
                else {

                    var newUser          = new User();


                    newUser.id    = profile.id;
                    newUser.token = token;
                    newUser.name  = profile.displayName;
                    newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value; 


                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err){
                            throw err;
                          }
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resorted to making a query to server checking if the user is loggedin before each access to a protected angular route.

To do that, I just "spy" on state changes in the app.run() using :

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, nextRoute, currentRoute){
        if(nextRoute.name === "login"){ //check if nextRoute is 'login' before proceeding to avoid infinite loop!
          return;
        }
// am I trying to access a restricted route ?
        if($location.path().indexOf('/restricted') != -1){ 
            authentification.checkLoggedIn($state);
        }
    });
```

chekLoggedIn() is a function of the service authentification which just uses $q.defer() to make a call to the server asking if the user is authenticated.

I'm not very experienced, so I would be very happy if someone could confirm that this is a secure way of doing things :)